# jfrog cli retrieve metadata

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have a job which uses the jfrog cli to access artifactory and pull down a resource. eg:

```
jfrog rt c shared01 --url="xxx" --user=xxx --password=xxx
jfrog rt dl --server-id shared01 --flat true "source/file" "./destfile"
```

This resource has some properties that I would like to retrieve. I can see from the documentation that you can retrieve where properties match XYZ, but I would just like to retrieve the metadata (we are storing the "product" version here).

Can anyone tell me if this is achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Search command seems to return the property metadata, at least on version 1.50.2

```
jfrog rt s --server-id shared01 "source/file"
```

outputs something like

```
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 1 artifact.
[
  {
    "path": "source/file",
    "type": "file",
    "size": 12345,
    "created": "2021-09-08T19:56:21.314Z",
    "modified": "2021-09-08T19:56:21.063Z",
    "sha1": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
    "md5": "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
    "props": {
      "someprop": [
        "value"
      ],
      "anotherprop": [
        "anothervalue"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The CLI doesn't have this capability build in. You can use a [REST API to get artifact's properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties).

Another possibility(which I haven't tried, but seems valid) is to use the [CLI Using File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UsingFileSpecs).
With File Specs you can search using [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language), where you can ask directly for the properties and filter per your needs.

Good Luck!